# Using a linear approximation to deduce that phase-paths are closed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

Considering the plane autonomous system below:

> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = ye^{xy}$$
>   $$ \frac{dy}{dt} = 1-x^{4} - y^{2}$$

I have been asked to show that the point $(1,0)$ is a critical point (it is a centre), and then to use $x = 1 + u$ and $y= v$ for $u,v$ sufficiently small to deduce that approximately
$$ 
\frac{du}{dt} = v \hspace{1cm} \frac{dv}{dt} = -4u.$$

I am not sure how to deduce the approximate result above, my working is as follows:

$$ \frac{du}{dt} = \frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = ve^{(1+u)v}$$
and
$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = 1 - (1+u)^{4} - v^{2}$$
How does the approximation result from this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have $x$ and $y$ mixed up? If you were analyzing (1,0), then the first order approximation of $x$ would be $x=x_0+x'dt = 1 +x'dt=1+u$, making $u$ equal to $x'dt$.

Comment: You are right! The critical point is at $(1,0)$ and not at $(0,1)$, that was a typo. Do you know how to work from this to get the approximation?

Comment: approximation of exp(x) roughly equal to 1+x? or (1+u)^4 approx 1+4u?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get
$$
ve^{u+uv}=v(1+u+u^2/2+...)(1+uv+u^2v^2/2+...)
$$
and 
$$
1-(1+u)^4-v^2=1-(1+4u+6u^2+4u^3+u^4)-v^2.
$$
Removing terms of degree 2 and higher leaves you with the linearization.

Answer (score 1):

The first-order approximation of $x$ is $x=x_0+\Delta x= x_0+x'\Delta t$

Here, $x_0 = 1$, so $x=1+x'\Delta t$, hence $u=x'\Delta t$. Similarly, $v = y'\Delta t$.

Then $\frac{du}{dt}=x'\Delta t=(ye^{xy})'\Delta t =[  y'e^{xy}+(x'y+xy')ye^{xy})]\Delta t$

Substituting in $x=1,y=0$, everything disappears except $y'\Delta t$, which is equal to $v$.

Similarly, $\frac{dv}{dt} = (1-x^4-y^2)'\Delta t = (-4x'x^3-2yy')\Delta t = -4x'\Delta t = -4u$